# Read numbers on the same line and store them in different varaibles

Tags: java

Trying to figure out how to read the numbers in the file and store them in different variables. I understand how hasNext works with strings, but not quite sure how to read the numbers on the same line. Running this prints out the first number, but not the second one.

[image]

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project1{

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException,FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File("candidates.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();

        Display the line.
        System.out.println("The first line in the file is: \n" + line);

        while(inputFile.hasNext()){
            int creds = inputFile.nextInt();
            System.out.println("credits : "+ creds);
        }

        // Close the file.
        inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506429/java-reading-multiple-ints-from-a-single-line

Answer (score 0):

For every second line:

```
String numbers = inputFile.nextLine().split(" ");
int i = Integer.valueOf(numbers[0]);
double d = Double.valueOf(numbers[1]);
```