# Java in/output result

Tags: java, arrays

I am quite new learner of java se, and i am coming to some problems.
The code below should be a calculator. It works fine But. To calculate the output the input of the scanner class should be entered like this:

1: enter 1st number - hit enter key on the keyboard

2: enter the case +-* or / then again hit the enter in keyboard

3: enter the second number and again hit the enter key

4: Finally comes the output

 so it looks like this

Calculator

2

-

1

Calculation is 1:

The question is is there a way to put it in a single row

1. Enter the both numbers 2-1 - hit the enter on the keyboard

2. The output shows like Calculation: 1

```
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        int num1;
        int num2;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Calculator");

        num1 = scan.nextInt();
        String str = scan.next();
        num2 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print(("Calculation is " + calculate(num1, str, num2)));
        scan.close();

    }

    private static int calculate(int num1, String str, int num2) {

        switch (str.charAt(0)) {
        case '+':
            return num1 + num2;
        case '-':
            return num1 - num2;
        case '*':
            return num1 * num2;
        case '/':
            return num1 / num2;

        }
        return calculate(num1, str, num2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java reading multiple ints from a single line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506429/java-reading-multiple-ints-from-a-single-line)

Comment: As I understand it is not the duplicate. He wants the user input to be displayed in a single row

Comment: You already can do that, just delimit each part with a space, like `2 - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the user's input to be displayed in a single line, then you can easily achieve this without changing a single line of code in your current implementation. You just simply need to separate your input with whitespace.

So rather than 2-1, simply use 2 - 1

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods...
>   [Scanner Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, the way to do that is to use a string to capture the whole operation then break it into different part.`public class application {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



    // get the operation from the user
    Scanner scan = new  Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your operation : ");

    String operation = scan.nextLine();


    // booleans to evaluate to true if a certain sign is use
    boolean isAddition = operation.contains("+");
    boolean isSubstration = operation.contains("-");
    boolean isDivision = operation.contains("/");
    boolean isMultiplication = operation.contains("*");

    if(isAddition){       
        // get result from the function in charge of processing the operation 
       int result = processOperation(operation, '+');
       //output the result
       System.out.println(" = "+result);
    }
    if(isSubstration){     
       // get result from the function in charge of processing the operation
       int result = processOperation(operation, '-');
       //output the result
       System.out.println(" = "+result);
    }
    if(isDivision){ 
    // get result from the function in charge of processing the operation 
       int result = processOperation(operation, '/');
       //output the result
       System.out.println(" = "+result);
    }
    if(isMultiplication){   
       // get result from the function in charge of processing the operation
       int result = processOperation(operation, '*');
       //output the result
       System.out.println(" = "+result);
    }
```

}

private static int processOperation(String operation, char sign){

```
        //remove all the whitespace in the string
        operation = operation.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

        // get the position of the sign operator in the String
        int signIndex = operation.indexOf(sign);

        //get the first number from the string which start from index 0 up to signIndex 
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(operation.substring(0, signIndex));

        //get the second number from the string which is start from signIndex 
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(operation.substring(signIndex+1));


        //evaluate the sign in use in order to perfom the appropriate operation 
    if (sign == '+') {
        return num1 + num2;
    } else if (sign == '-') {
        return num1 - num2;
    } else if (sign == '*') {
        return num1 * num2;
    } else {
        return num1 / num2;
    }
}
```

}`