# Issues with loops? Program runs as it should but test keep failing. Java using TMCbeans

Tags: java, loops

I am doing an open university course in Java, it's been smooth sailing up until now. We are covering loops in this section and the problem I am stuck on asks for the following.

> Write a program that reads values from the user until they input a 0.
>   After this, the program prints the total number of inputted values
>   that are negative. The zero that's used to exit the loop should not be
>   included in the total number count.

This is my the program I have written and I have run the program and it works as it should, however I keep getting failed test back with the following statement.

> When input was: 5 4 -3 1 0  "Give a number:" text should appear a total of 5 times. Now the count was 0 expected:<5> but was:<0>

Here is my code, as I said when I run the program locally it seems to work just as asked for.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberOfNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numbers = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Give a number.");
            int number = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine()); 
            if (number == 0){
                break; 
            }
            if (number >= 1){
                numbers = numbers + 1;
            } 
        }
        System.out.println("number of values is " + numbers);

    }
}
```

Comment: You're printing `Give a number.`, it expects the output `Give a number:`

Comment: `scanner.nextLine()` will take the line not individual number. check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23506492/7505731

Comment: Also, Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and get your first badge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems with the code :

1. In the number test line,you check if a number is greater than or equal to one (`number >= 1`), but you should check that it is less than 0 because it is need to be negative numbers. **(In the question : the total number of inputted values that are negative)**
2. You are using with `scanner.nextLine()` But you don't get a line, you get a number (Int if it's integers, double if it's decimal numbers)  on you to change it to : `scanner.nextInt()` :

**Here the code :**

```
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          int numbers = 0;
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Give a number.");
                int number = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextInt());// Scanner number !! 
                if (number == 0){
                    break; 
                }
                if (number < 0){ // Less then zero !!!
                    numbers = numbers + 1;
                } 
            }
            System.out.println("number of values is " + numbers);
```

Comment: Thanks! totally have been missing over that when trouble shooting. and thanks for the advice for the scanner.nextInt(); They haven't mentioned using that for Int yet in this course but it makes sense!

Comment: I was glad to help and good luck! If you can  accept the answer to the community I would be very happy!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement says that the count of negative numbers should be the output. But what you are returning is the count of positive numbers. Change the condition from if (number >= 1) to if (number < 0).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need **the total number of inputted values that are negative**. So the condition in the while loop has to change from `number >= 1` to `number < 0`.
Check this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberOfNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numbers = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Give a number.");
            int number = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextInt());
            if (number == 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (number < 0) {
                numbers = numbers + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("number of values is " + numbers);

    }
}
```

Also, prefer to use `nextInt()` because you know your input is of integer type.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the exact problem. But some observations.

1. If you really input all numbers at the first ask and then hitting ENTER, obviously it would throw NumberFormatException as "5 4 -3.." is not a valid number and the loop wont proceed. Try input each number and hit ENTER.
2. Scanner must be closed. If you are using JDK 8, use "try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {...}. This would automatically close the scanner.