# How to read 3 Integer values in single line of input in Java?

Tags: java, int

How do you scan 3 variable in one line 
its like i have 3 int variable named ( x , y and z)
I want to input the three of them in a single line

i can input like this 
7 21 35  < single line

```
        int x = 7;
        int y = 21;
        int z = 35;

        x = sc.nextInt();
        y = sc.nextInt();
        z = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("%2d, %2d, %2d\n", x, y, z);
```

I have found something in C++ their code is like this  ( scanf ("%lf %lf %lf", &x, &y, &z); )

Comment: and what is wrong with what you have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java reading multiple ints from a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506429/java-reading-multiple-ints-from-a-single-line)

Comment: What i have is i can only input the integers in each line. I would like to input the 3 integers in a single line using spaces..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is small example for you

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

   String[] input = new String[3]; 
   int x; 
   int y;
   int z;

   System.out.print("Please enter Three integers: "); 
   input = in.readLine().split(" "); 

   x = Integer.parseInt(input[0]); 
   y = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
   z = Integer.parseInt(input[2]); 

   System.out.println("You input: " + x + ", " + y + " and " + z); 
}
```