# how to create binary search tree 2d model from these codes?

Tags: java, tree

hi im new to codings and i have to print my binary search tree in a 2d model but this codes only print the orders of number in order(left-root-right) such as when i insert 10, 9, 11, 8, it will print inorder (left root right) = 8,9,10,11. what method or codes should i add to create a 2d tree here. sorry idk how to properly put the codes here just look at it like it is only a one code only.

```
 class binarySearchTree { 

   class Node { 
    int key; 
    Node left, right; 
    int data;
    public Node(int data){ 
        key = data; 
        left = right = null; 
    } 
} 
// BST root node 
Node root; 

   // Constructor for BST =>initial empty tree
   binarySearchTree(){ 
    root = null; 
} 
//delete a node from BST
void deleteKey(int key) { 
    root = delete_Recursive(root, key); 
} 

//recursive delete function
Node delete_Recursive(Node root, int key)  { 
    //tree is empty
    if (root == null)  return root; 

    //traverse the tree
    if (key < root.key)     //traverse left subtree 
        root.left = delete_Recursive(root.left, key); 
    else if (key > root.key)  //traverse right subtree
        root.right = delete_Recursive(root.right, key); 
    else  { 
        // node contains only one child
        if (root.left == null) 
            return root.right; 
        else if (root.right == null) 
            return root.left; 

        // node has two children; 
        //get inorder successor (min value in the right subtree) 
        root.key = minValue(root.right); 

        // Delete the inorder successor 
        root.right = delete_Recursive(root.right, root.key); 
    } 
    return root; 
} 

int minValue(Node root)  { 
    //initially minval = root
    int minval = root.key; 
    //find minval
    while (root.left != null)  { 
        minval = root.left.key; 
        root = root.left; 
    } 
    return minval; 
} 

// insert a node in BST 
void insert(int key)  { 
    root = insert_Recursive(root, key); 
} 

//recursive insert function
Node insert_Recursive(Node root, int key) { 
      //tree is empty
    if (root == null) { 
        root = new Node(key); 
        return root; 
    } 
    //traverse the tree
    if (key < root.key)     //insert in the left subtree
        root.left = insert_Recursive(root.left, key); 
    else if (key > root.key)    //insert in the right subtree
        root.right = insert_Recursive(root.right, key); 
      // return pointer
    return root; 
} 


void inorder() { 
    inorder_Recursive(root); 
} 

// recursively traverse the BST  
void inorder_Recursive(Node root) { 
    if (root != null) { 
        inorder_Recursive(root.left); 
        System.out.print(root.key + " x "); 
        inorder_Recursive(root.right); 
    } 
} 
 
  
 //PostOrder Traversal - Left:Right:rootNode (LRn)
void postOrder(Node node)  { 
    if (node == null) 
        return; 

    // first traverse left subtree recursively 
    postOrder(node.left); 

    // then traverse right subtree recursively 
    postOrder(node.right); 

    // now process root node 
    System.out.print(node.key + " "); 
} 
     // InOrder Traversal - Left:rootNode:Right (LnR) 
void inOrder(Node node)  { 
    if (node == null) 
        return; 
    //first traverse left subtree recursively
    inOrder(node.left); 

    //then go for root node
    System.out.print(node.key + " "); 

    //next traverse right subtree recursively
    inOrder(node.right); 
} 

   //PreOrder Traversal - rootNode:Left:Right (nLR)
void preOrder(Node node)  { 
    if (node == null) 
        return; 

    //first print root node first
    System.out.print(node.key + " "); 
    // then traverse left subtree recursively
    preOrder(node.left); 
    // next traverse right subtree recursively
    preOrder(node.right); 
} 
   // Wrappers for recursive functions 
void postOrder_traversal()  {    
    postOrder(root);  } 
void inOrder_traversal() { 
    inOrder(root);   } 
void preOrder_traversal() {
    preOrder(root);  } 

 }
```

here i found this codes in stackoverflow, i want te output like this, i can use this but i dont know how can i make this as user input for the data and make it insert the integer into a tree not this manually inserted of the integer. thankyou very much to whoever put effort to understand my question and my situation as newbie.

```
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

    public class BTreePrinterTest {

         private static Node<Integer> test2() {

    Node<Integer> root = new Node<Integer>(2);
    Node<Integer> n11 = new Node<Integer>(3);
    Node<Integer> n12 = new Node<Integer>(5);
    Node<Integer> n21 = new Node<Integer>(2);
    Node<Integer> n22 = new Node<Integer>(6);
    Node<Integer> n23 = new Node<Integer>(9);
    Node<Integer> n31 = new Node<Integer>(5);
   
    
    root.left = n11;
    root.right = n12;
    
    n11.left = n21;
    n11.right = n22;

    
    n12.left = n23;
    n12.right = n31;

    return root;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    BTreePrinter.printNode(test2());

   }
   }

   class Node<T extends Comparable<?>> {
Node<T> left, right;
T data;

public Node(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}
  }

 class BTreePrinter {

public static <T extends Comparable<?>> void printNode(Node<T> root) {
    int maxLevel = BTreePrinter.maxLevel(root);

    printNodeInternal(Collections.singletonList(root), 1, maxLevel);
}

private static <T extends Comparable<?>> void printNodeInternal(List<Node<T>> nodes, int level, int maxLevel) {
    if (nodes.isEmpty() || BTreePrinter.isAllElementsNull(nodes))
        return;

    int floor = maxLevel - level;
    int endgeLines = (int) Math.pow(2, (Math.max(floor - 1, 0)));
    int firstSpaces = (int) Math.pow(2, (floor)) - 1;
    int betweenSpaces = (int) Math.pow(2, (floor + 1)) - 1;

    BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(firstSpaces);

    List<Node<T>> newNodes = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    for (Node<T> node : nodes) {
        if (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data);
            newNodes.add(node.left);
            newNodes.add(node.right);
        } else {
            newNodes.add(null);
            newNodes.add(null);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(betweenSpaces);
    }
    System.out.println("");

    for (int i = 1; i <= endgeLines; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(firstSpaces - i);
            if (nodes.get(j) == null) {
                BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(endgeLines + endgeLines + i + 1);
                continue;
            }

            if (nodes.get(j).left != null)
                System.out.print("/");
            else
                BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(1);

            BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(i + i - 1);

            if (nodes.get(j).right != null)
                System.out.print("\\");
            else
                BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(1);

            BTreePrinter.printWhitespaces(endgeLines + endgeLines - i);
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }

    printNodeInternal(newNodes, level + 1, maxLevel);
}

private static void printWhitespaces(int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        System.out.print(" ");
}

private static <T extends Comparable<?>> int maxLevel(Node<T> node) {
    if (node == null)
        return 0;

    return Math.max(BTreePrinter.maxLevel(node.left), BTreePrinter.maxLevel(node.right)) + 1;
}

private static <T> boolean isAllElementsNull(List<T> list) {
    for (Object object : list) {
        if (object != null)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

  }
```

btw im learning this by my own, i tried merging the two codes but it gives me error i cant fix it.

Comment: Sorry I can not understand the sentence "i want te output like this, i can use this but i dont know how can i make this as user input for the data and make it insert the integer into a tree not this manually inserted of the integer.". Can you rephraze or explain it?

Comment: Also be carefull to not confuse b-tree with binary tree.

Comment: hi sorry for the confusion, the 2nd codes is a different one. there it only assigned manually the nodes including the root as well as if the node is in left of the root or right of the root. you can see it in the codes

Comment: i want my user input number like 1 2 3 4 5 in a 2d form or graphical way. the first codes it only produce numbers but not in 2d. in 2nd codes, it produces a 2d form of tree but it is not a user input plus it manually assigns where the nodes should be located either in the left or right side of the root

Answer (score 0):

I should have not made the whole exercise for you, so please try to understand the code. Tell me if something is not clear for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Write your input");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String lines = br.readLine();    
    binarySearchTree b = new binarySearchTree();
    b.input(lines);
    b.print();
}
```

These functions go to `binarySearchTree`.

```
    protected void printRecursive(Node node, int depth) {
        System.out.println("");
        for(int i = 0; i<depth; i++) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        System.out.print(node.key);
        if(node.left != null) {
            printRecursive(node.left, depth + 1);
        }
        if(node.right != null) {
            printRecursive(node.right, depth + 1); 
        }
    }
```

```
    public void input(String s) throws IOException {
        String[] strs = s.trim().split("\\s+");
                
        for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
            insert(Integer.parseInt(strs[i]));
        }
    }
```

Also i used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26654259/9983678) in my code.