# error: bad operand types for binary operator '%'

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to print Even or Odd number entered in a single in java but getting this error message in console

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '%'
    if ( (num % 2) == 0 )
              ^
  first type:  int[]
  second type: int
1 error
```

My code is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class EvenOdd{
  public static void main(String args[])
    {
    
    Scanner sc = new 
    Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an Integer number:");
    
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    int[] num = new int[n];

    for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++) {
        
    if ( (num % 2) == 0 )
    {
        System.out.println("The number "+num+" is even");
    }
     else{
        System.out.println("The number "+num+" is odd");
    }
    }
    }
}
```

First i tried to search on internet then i found that may be its due to precedence of operator , then i put `num % 2` in bracket but still getting this error message. Please help.

Comment: Please read the error message. It says `first type:  int[]`. You're trying to use the operator on `num`, which is an array. You probably meant `num[i] % 2 == 0`

Comment: You're trying to apply the modulo to an array, not the element. Try to use the index, `num [i]` in your case.

Comment: `num` is an array; did you mean `num[i]`?

Comment: `num` is an `int[]` or in other words: It is not a single number but an array of multiple numbers. The `%` operator can only be used on a single `int` and not on an array. But why are you creating that array anyway? The number the user enters is already saved in the variable `int n = sc.nextInt();` so you should just test that single number and delete whatever you were trying to do by initializing a pointless array.

Comment: one more thing how to get all numbers which user writes in single line of console e.g. 1 2 3 4 .. and check if they are odd or even and print respectively?

Comment: @AbhishekTiwari [How to read multiple Integer values from a single line of input in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506429/how-to-read-multiple-integer-values-from-a-single-line-of-input-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the if there you got the error, you should reference that value in the array, num[i] instead of the array itself.
That also goes for your print statements further down.

Comment: one more thing how to get all numbers which user writes in single line of console e.g. 1 2 3 4 .. and check if they are odd or even and print respectively?

Comment: I'm confused   isn't that what your if-statement is doing?

Comment: Enter an Integer number:
3 4 5 6
The number 0 is even
The number 0 is even
The number 0 is even i am getting this after running program

Comment: Oh I see. Your code is only allocating an array but never fills it with values. The default if ant int i 0.