# How to find max number and occurrences

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, integer, java.util.scanner

So I'm learn java for the first time and can't seem to figure how to set up a while loop properly .

my assignment is Write a program that reads integers, finds the largest of them, and counts its occurrences.

But I have 2 problems and some handicaps. I'm not allowed to use an array or list because we haven't learned that, So how do you take multiple inputs from the user on the same line . I posted what I can up so far . I am also having a problem with getting the loop to work . I am not sure what to set the the while condition not equal to create a sential Value. I tried if the user input is 0 put I cant use user input because its inside the while statement . Side note I don't think a loop is even needed to create this in the first place couldn't I just use a chain of if else statement to accomplish this .

```
 package myjavaprojects2;
import java.util.*;
public class Max_number_count {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        int max = 1;
        System.out.print("Enter a Integer:");
        int userInput = input.nextInt();    

        while ( userInput != 0) {
           
                        
        if (userInput > max) {
            int temp = userInput;
            userInput = max;
            max = temp;
         } else if (userInput == max) {
             count++ ;
             
             
         }
             
    
        System.out.println("The max number is " + max );
        System.out.println("The count is " + count );
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173354/529282

Comment: `if (userInput > max) { max = userInput; count = 1; }` Not sure why you felt the need for a swap, and you forgot to set `count` to `1`. Good luck.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash The precise answer I linked literally have the same method call as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how do you take multiple inputs from the user on the same line .

You can use scanner and nextInput method as in your code. However, because nextInt only read 1 value separated by white space at a time, you need to re-assign your userInput varible at the end of while loop to update the current processing value as below.

```
 int userInput = input.nextInt();    

    while ( userInput != 0) {
      //all above logic
      userInput = input.nextInt();        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int max = 0, count = 0, num;

        System.out.println("Enter numbers:-");
        while ((num = sc.nextInt()) != 0) {
            if (num > max) {
                max = num;
                count = 1;
            } else if (num == max) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nCount of maximum number = "+count);
    }
}
```

And you don't have to use ArrayList or Array. Just keep inputting numbers till you get 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this with a single loop. The traditional concise pattern for doing so involves the fact that assignment resolved to the value assigned. Thus your loop can use `(x = input.nextInt()) != 0` to terminate (handling exceptions, and non-integer input left as an exercise for the reader). Remember to display the max and count ***after*** the loop and reset the count to `1` when you find a new max. Also, I would default max to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (not `1`). That leaves the code looking something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a Integer:");
    int count = 0, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, userInput;
    while ((userInput = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
        if (userInput > max) {
            max = userInput;
            count = 1;
        } else if (userInput == max) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The max number is " + max);
    System.out.println("The count is " + count);
}
```