# Multiple loops printing in last line JAVA

Tags: java

I am currently working with arrays and loop and I found it strange that the 'Enter the values' were printing in multiple line. You can refer to the Output of Source Code and the Expected output.
Source code of Mine:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Mains {
    public static int father(int[] arr, int len) {
        int first, second, third;
        int min = -(int)2_147_483_648l;
        first = min;
        second = min;
        third = min;
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(arr[i] > first) {
                third = second;
                second = first;
                first = arr[i];
            } else if(arr[i] > second ) {
                third = second;
                second = arr[i];
            } else if(arr[i] > third) {
                third = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return first + second + third;
    }

    public static int son(int[] arr, int len) 
    {
        int first, second, third;

        int max = 2_147_483_647;
        first = max;
        second = max;
        third = max;
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        {
            if(arr[i] < first)
            {
                third = second;
                second = first;
                first = arr[i];
            } 
            else if (arr[i] <second)      
            {
                    third = second;
                    second = arr[i];
            }

            else if (arr[i] < third)
            {
                    third = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return first+second+third;
    }

    public static void main(String []args) 
    {
        Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
        int num;        
        System.out.print("Enter the size: ");
        num = x.nextInt();

        int array [] = new int [num];
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
            System.out.print("Enter the values: ");
            array[i] = x.nextInt();
            
            
        }

        System.out.print("Father = "+father(array, num)+", Son = "+son(array, num));
        x.close();
    }
}
```

Output of the Source Code:

```
Enter the size: 4
Enter the values: 1 2 3 4
Enter the values: Enter the values: Enter the values: Father = 9, Son = 6
```

Expected Output:

```
Enter the size: 4
Enter the values: 1 2 3 4
Father = 9, Son = 6
```

And I do not know what is the problem and I am keeping searching on how to remove that. Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Use `System.out.println()` if you want newlines.

Comment: just move the print outside the loop. everything inside the loop is executed `num` times

Comment: You will get the expected output if you do not enter the numbers as "1 2 3 4<RETURN>" but as "1<RETURN>2<RETURN>3<RETURN>4<RETURN>".
The line-breaks you see in the output do not come from your code but from your input.

Comment: `num` is 4. So your for-loop runs 4 times. So your `print` statement inside the loop is executed 4 times.

Comment: Can you expound more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you enter the value `4` for `num`, it is looping 4 times.

Also, you are trying to get the input of integers entered in a single line separated by a `space`, and not a `return`.

If you want to read multiple Integer values from a single line of input in Java, you can do something like below.

(Referred from - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26654259/5384491))

```
Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the size: ");
int num = x.nextInt();

int array [] = new int[num];
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String lines = br.readLine();    
    
String[] strs = lines.trim().split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    array[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
}
```

This will store the integers in the variable `array`.

Note: This works well, if you are sure that the `size` entered and then the no. of `values` entered are same. You might have to handle scenarios where they doesn't match.